# How to Design Complex Interfces in Android

Tags: android

I want to design this kind of Interface in android Tab. I tried a lot using different Layouts, But couldn't.

[image: Interface of the application]

Comment: you can use relative layout!!

Comment: what you have tried?
please show some code what you have done to achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whats complex here ?
**Change ids according to need** 
**Manage height and width**

```
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Large Text"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />
        </TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/tableRow2"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

            <LinearLayout
                xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:orientation="horizontal" >

                <ListView
                    android:id="@+id/listView1"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
                </ListView>

                <ListView
                    android:id="@+id/listView1"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
                </ListView>
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:orientation="horizontal" >

                <TableRow
                    android:id="@+id/tableRow2"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

                    <Button
                        android:id="@+id/button1"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="Button" />

                    <Button
                        android:id="@+id/button2"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="Button" />
                </TableRow>

                <TableRow
                    android:id="@+id/tableRow2"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

                    <ListView
                        android:id="@+id/listView1"
                        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
                    </ListView>
                </TableRow>
            </LinearLayout>
        </TableRow>        
    </LinearLayout>
```

**Edit : 1**

This will help a lot this is with alignment and mind one thing either set witdth according to your need or it will take the max in column

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TableLayout
        android:id="@+id/tableLayout1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:stretchColumns="6" >

        <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/tableRow1"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_column="0"
                android:text="Button" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button2"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_column="1"
                android:text="Button" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_column="2"
                android:layout_span="4"
                android:text="Large Text"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />
        </TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/tableRow2"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

            <LinearLayout
                xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_column="0"
                android:layout_span="4"
                android:orientation="horizontal" >

                <ListView
                    android:id="@+id/listView1"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
                </ListView>

                <ListView
                    android:id="@+id/listView1"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
                </ListView>
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_column="1"
                android:layout_span="2"
                android:orientation="horizontal" >

                <TableRow
                    android:id="@+id/tableRow2"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

                    <Button
                        android:id="@+id/button1"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="Button" />

                    <Button
                        android:id="@+id/button2"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="Button" />
                </TableRow>

                <TableRow
                    android:id="@+id/tableRow2"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

                    <ListView
                        android:id="@+id/listView1"
                        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
                    </ListView>
                </TableRow>
            </LinearLayout>
        </TableRow>
    </TableLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: The harder thing was alignment

Comment: neither i  know the Pixel size of your screen nor the i have the same so try with either Weightsum or with tableLayout and column and colspan